# Advanced TMemo functionality

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, tmemo

Good day,
Tell me, is it possible to implement a component TMemo following functionality:

1. Entering text in TMemo, begin the search for the first character you type;
2. If a match is found, we conclude that the choice in a list whose elements are displayed as links, then click on the found text that stands out in TMemo.
3. Click on the link right - go to the found text similar to item 2

Whether it is possible to implement a standard TMemo, or to look for a component?

Comment: Yes, it can be done using a standard TMemo, but it will require quite a bit of programming.

Comment: Could you show a small example of use? thanks

Comment: Well, none of the functionality exists by default in TMemo, so you'll have to add everything by adding events or create your own descendant. Hard to put that in a small example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delphi is known for the ease you can extend the existing components and transform them in custom ones.

If you never developed a component before the topic might seem a bit confusing so i recomend you first document your self on the topic by consulting this guide : http://delphi.about.com/od/vclusing/a/customvcldev.htm

After you done some coding come back and ask us what you tried and didn't work.

Hope it helps